# Plain Dygraphs JavaScript options in R/Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dygraphs

Is there a way to use plain Dygraphs JavaScript options in R (and Shiny more in specific)?
http://dygraphs.com/options.html

I think the `JS()` function from the htmlwidgets package can be of use, but am not sure.

For example, I want to use `highlightSeriesOpts` (cf. first link) to highlight individual series in a dygraphs plot in order to display ONLY the selected series in the legend (and not all series at the same time by default). The lower 2 plots in the following link show exactly what is to be achieved:
http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-series

A CSS solution has already been given ( i.e. `.dygraph-legend  {display: none;}` and `.dygraph-legend .highlight {display: inline;}` ), but that somehow does not work in R/Shiny.

Anyhow, here is a conceptual script of mine. It does not work, but all advice is much appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(dygraphOutput("plot"))

  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  set.seed(123)
  data <- matrix(rnorm(12), ncol = 2)
  data <- ts(data)

  # Workaround for what might be a bug
  # Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305610/use-dygraph-for-r-to-plot-xts-time-series-by-year-only
  data <- cbind(as.xts(data[,1]), as.xts(data[,2]))

  colnames(data) <- c("Series 1", "Series 2")
  #print(data) # Uncomment to view data frame

  # The logic of the following is that plain Dygraphs JavaScript
  # code can be used as plotting material
  output$plot <- JS("
                     new Dygraph(plot,
                                 data,
                                 { highlightSeriesOpts: {strokeWidth: 3} });

                     g.updateOptions({ highlightSeriesOpts: {strokeWidth: 3} });

                    ")

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but why not simply use https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/ ?

Comment: I am already using the dygraphs package for R :). However, there is no convenient built-in feature to display only the highlighted series in the legend. CSS is required for this feature, but the provided CSS code on the dygraphs website somehow does not work in R/Shiny. Most likely it is being overwritten during execution. So is there any way to trace this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `highlightSeriesOpts` causes the highlighted series stroke to be bolder and does not affect the legend.  You will still need the proper `CSS` to only show the closest series in the legend.  To set the `highlightSeriesOpts` as you suggest, there is a clear example at http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-series-highlighting.html.

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)

dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 3))
```

For a fuller answer in Shiny, we could do something like this.

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)

ui <- dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 3)) %>%
  dyCSS(textConnection("
     .dygraph-legend > span { display: none; }
     .dygraph-legend > span.highlight { display: inline; }
  "))

server <- function(input,output,session){

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you! `.dygraph-legend > span {display:none;}` and `.dygraph-legend > span.highlight {display:inline;}` did the trick :). It is important to note that `> span` is necessary to make it work in R/Shiny. CSS code I found previously (cf. OP), did not mention this.